# set cookie in jquery for hide/show div block

Tags: jquery, cookies

After clicking on "Close block" action is not saved when the page is refreshed. What am I doing wrong?

Prompt please, 
Thank you in advance.

```
$(window).load(function(){

// setup the initial display on page load
var menu_state = $.cookie('welcome');

    if( typeof menu_state !== "undefined" && menu_state == "hidden" ) {
        $('#welcome_block').hide; // visible, and cookie is set
        $.cookie('welcome', 'hidden'); // set the cookie
        console.log( 'hide' );
        console.log( $.cookie('welcome') );
    } else {
        $('#welcome_block').show; // hidden or cookie is not set, set just in case
        $.removeCookie('welcome'); // prevent multiple instances
        console.log( 'show' );
    }

    console.log( $.cookie('welcome') );

    $('.disabled').click(function() {
        console.log( 'disable block' );

        $('#welcome_block').toggle();
        $.removeCookie('welcome'); // prevent multiple instances
        $.cookie('welcome', 'hidden'); // update (or set) the cookie
        $(".disabled").css("display", "none");
        $(".enabled").css("display", "block");
        //console.log( $.cookie('welcome') );
    });

    $('.enabled').click(function() {
        console.log( 'enable block' );

        $('#welcome_block').toggle();
        $.removeCookie('welcome'); // prevent multiple instances
        $.cookie('welcome', 'visible'); // update (or set) the cookie
        $(".disabled").css("display", "block");
        $(".enabled").css("display", "none");
        //console.log( $.cookie('welcome') );
    });

});
```

More: http://jsfiddle.net/narzankmv/bwLSu/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You use methods "hide" & "show" without ()
2. This methods use css prop. "display", not "visibility"
3. This is work sample of JS code to you HTML:

   ```
   $(window).load(function(){
   // setup the initial display on page load
   var menu_state = $.cookie('welcome');

   if( (typeof menu_state !== "undefined") && (menu_state == "hidden")) {
       $('#welcome_block').css("visibility", "hidden");
       $(".enabled").css("display", "block");
       // visible, and cookie is set
   } else {
       $(".enabled").css("display", "none");
       $('#welcome_block').css("visibility", "visible") 
       // hidden or cookie is not set, set just in case
   }

   $('.disabled').click(function() {        
       $('#welcome_block').css("visibility", "hidden");
       $.removeCookie('welcome'); // prevent multiple instances
       $.cookie('welcome', 'hidden'); // update (or set) the cookie
       $(".disabled").css("display", "none");
       $(".enabled").css("display", "block");
       //console.log( $.cookie('welcome') );
   });

   $('.enabled').click(function() {
       $('#welcome_block').css("visibility", "visible");
       $.removeCookie('welcome'); // prevent multiple instances
       $.cookie('welcome', 'visible'); // update (or set) the cookie
       $(".disabled").css("display", "block");
       $(".enabled").css("display", "none");
       //console.log( $.cookie('welcome') );
   }); });
   ```